# Using "CKEditor" with Django "Machina Forums?"

Tags: python, django, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

This is a more-general question – just hoping to find someone who already knows.

("To save my forehead," y'know.) ;-)

I want to use CKEditor in conjunction with Machina forums, and I *specifically* want to be able to "drag and drop" images. I've found the right CKEditor feature to do that, but I'm getting "Incorrect Server Response" messages from CKEditor when I try to accomplish the drop. (This also happens on my development box.)

(Note that my concern is quite-particular to Django ("django-ckeditor"), and to the Machina forum software ("django-machina").  I need answers that are very tightly focused upon *this* use-case.)

So is there anyone out there who might say – "oh yeah, that happened to me, too, and the way to fix it is ...?"

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you know?  I figured it out.

The problem was – and, as the `django-ckeditor` documentation clearly states, the default `urlpattern` entries (in the `include` file) specify a "staff-only" decorator for uploads.  So, `ckeditor` was getting an error-message response and of course it didn't know what to do.

To solve the problem:

First, of course, be sure that `ckeditor_uploader` (as well as `ckeditor`) is installed on your system and is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`.

Now, in your `urls.py`, first add this line near the top:

`from ckeditor_uploader import views as uploader_views`

Next, insert the `urlpattern` entries that you find in the package's `urls.py` file, *but referencing the `uploader_views`alias*, viz:

```
url(r'^ckeditor/upload/',
    uploader_views.upload, name='ckeditor_upload'),
url(r'^ckeditor/browse/',
    never_cache(uploader_views.browse), name='ckeditor_browse'),
```

If you erroneously attempt to specify `ckeditor_uploader.views.` in the `url()` entry, you will be rewarded with:

`NameError: name 'ckeditor_uploader' is not defined`

*Now you know!*  `:-)`

---

Also, don't forget what the Machina documentation told you to remember: `;-)`

`MACHINA_MARKUP_WIDGET = 'ckeditor_uploader.widgets.CKEditorUploadingWidget'`

If you're doing "drag and drop," you're necessarily doing "file uploads," so you must use the provided field-types or *(equivalently ...)* the provided widgets from the `ckeditor_uploader` app.